# how to output javascript array in to a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, pusher

I have a javascript array that records calls coming in from all 50 states, I wrote the array so that the values don't repeat themselves when getting a new call from the same state. The problem is its not connected to my table.I only have the location being outputed to my table and its repeating itself. I want to output to be the same data in my array so they don't repeat, but be able to still use the data associated with that locaton, how would I do that?

this is my code

```
var states = [];

channel.bind('call', function(data) {
    var location = data.location;
    var call_id = data.call_id;
    var status = data.status;
    if (states.indexOf(location) === -1) {
       states.push(location);
    }

    var output = '<tr class="phonedata"><td>' + location + '</td></tr>';
    $('.table').append(output);

    return output;
});
```

Comment: Are you using pure javascript?  Or is that JQuery?  If so, add the appropriate tag (and you might also mention it specifically in your question body as well).

Comment: I'm using mostly javascript, and some jquery, and the pusher api, added the tags

Comment: I strongly recommend using a library that supports data binding, such as [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) or [Angular](https://angularjs.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use List.js library.
Here is an [example](http://www.listjs.com/examples).

```
<div id="users">
  <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <button class="sort" data-sort="name">
    Sort by name
  </button>

  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <h3 class="name">Jonny Stromberg</h3>
      <p class="born">1986</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3 class="name">Jonas Arnklint</h3>
      <p class="born">1985</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3 class="name">Martina Elm</h3>
      <p class="born">1986</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3 class="name">Gustaf Lindqvist</h3>
      <p class="born">1983</p>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
<script src="http://listjs.com/no-cdn/list.js"></script>

<script>
var options = {
  valueNames: [ 'name', 'born' ]
};

var userList = new List('users', options);
</script>
```